# pass parameter to a program through html link

Tags: html, windows, parameters

I need to run a program from the local user's file system by clicking an html link.

When i use this

```
<a href="C:\Windows\System32\NETSTAT.EXE">CLICK</a>
```

It works fine. But When i try to pass a parameter to the exe file it fails.

```
<a href="C:\Windows\System32\NETSTAT.EXE -a">CLICK</a>
```

Anyone has an idea how is it possible to pass the parameter?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The use of this is the following: An online system sends emails to users if a new record is available in the system. Therefore the users will click a **link** from their email client that will open their local exe program with the desired parameter, to show the new record.

I don't want to send emails with bat files since it is not allowed by my network admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see only one solution, use .BAT file, where will be "netstat.exe -a", named for example netstat-a.bat.

```
<a href="C:\Windows\System32\NETSTAT-A.BAT">CLICK</a>
```

It's quite impertect solution, but can works :)

You can also try this code, but it depend of browser and user rights:

```
<html>
 <head>
     <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
         MyObject = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" ) 
         function RunNotePad()  
         { 
            MyObject.Run("netstat.exe -a") ; 
        } 

    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>Run a Program</h1>
    This script launch the file >> c:\windows\notepad.exe<p>
    <button onclick="RunNotePad()">Run Windows NotePad</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes it works like this but this is not what i actually need. You see the program is installed on the client, and by an email i want the user to be able to run the program with the parameter. I don't want to email bat files ..., having the user downloading it and then running it.

Comment: uuu... in this case is possible to use javascript code, but functionality of code will depend of used browser/version, user rights... and it's not from my head :)

Answer (score 0):

As from my point of view as
`<A>` is case sensitive it will treat `C:\Windows\System32\NETSTAT.EXE -a` as whole path rather than `-a` as an argument.
Above link is working as it also take as an argument and it is there inside system32 that why it execute

Similarly it a treat  `<a href="C:\Windows\System32\NETSTAT.EXE -a">CLICK</a>` as a whole file which is not there so there is only one method to solve the problem make it as .bat the whole path and save it and give the path in and save netstat-a.bat or whatever you want in `<a>` and give that whole path in `<a>C:\Windows\System32\NETSTAT.EXE-a.bat</a>`