# Specify arguments in the application path

Tags: c#

I have an Aplication with path: "C:\App\Aplication.lnk"
(I am using a shortcut because I need to specify arguments, maybe it can be done with the .exe?)

This aplicaion is exected using an HTML link to this path inside an email.

```
 "<a style =\"text-decoration: none; font-family: calibri; font-size:12pt; border: 20px solid #00468c; background-color: #00468c; color: white;\" href=" + Aplication2 + ">Deny request</a><br>" +
```

Where string aplication2 = "C:\App\Aplication.lnk"

This way works perfect, the App executes.

What I need now is to execute this App with an argument not included in the Shortcut.

Something like:

```
argument = "155"
aplication2 = "C:\App\Aplication.lnk " + argument;
```

If I do this, an error apprear saying that the path "C:\App\Aplication.lnk 155" does not exist.

How can I do this?

**Update:**

The link "pass parameter to a program through html link" does not solve it, I do not want to add bat files in the process because I cannot run them "easily" without prompts in my network.

Comment: have you specify this link in to mail?

Comment: Yes, it is an HTML link. You can see it in the first post.

Comment: so where this html link will you use? Inside html page!!

Comment: It's HTML code atached inside the eMail. It Works perfect with no arguments. I need to modify somehow the path to specify the argument.

Comment: You cannot pass argument to a shortcut file (.lnk), it defies the purpose of a shortcut file. Use exe file instead or include  a static argument to your lnk file or create a seperate lnk file for each argument and append them on conditions into your HTML.

Comment: But how can I specify the argument in the exe path? string Aplication2 = C:\App\Aplication.exe 155"; Does not work.

And I cannot create separate shortcuts because there are infinite arguments. The argument it's basically a variable send by App1 and read by App2 when executed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass parameter to a program through html link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210557/pass-parameter-to-a-program-through-html-link)

Comment: Thank you Thomas, but it's not a good solution for me. There must be a way to send a link with a paramater included...

Comment: I think the Target in lin file property should be like this: *"C:\App\Aplication.exe " 155*, where "155" is the argument.

Process proc = new Process();

proc.StartInfo.FileName = ""C:\App\Aplication";

proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "155";

proc.Start();